# Why giving syntax error in octave with ODE system

Tags: syntax, system, octave, ode

It seems to be a parse/syntax error for my system of ODE specially xdot(2). But I am unable to figure out

I 've checked similar question in StackOverflow but i don't find my solution

```
function xdot = f3(x, t)
      xdot =zeros(2, 1);
      x=zeros(1, 2);

      r_1=4;
      R_1=1;
      p_1=8;
      l_1=0.2;
      r_2=10;
      p_2=10;
      R_2=2;
      l_2=50;
      rM= 0.01;
      d=2;

      xdot(1)= ((r_1*p_1*x(3))/(1+p_1*x(3)))*x(1)-r_1*x(1)^2-(R-1*x(1))/(1+r_1*x(3)-x(1)*x(2)
      xdot(2)= rM + ((r_2*p_2*x(3))/(1+p_2*x(3)))*x(2)-r_2*x(2)^2-(R_2*x(2))/(1+p_2*x(3))
      xdot(3)= d - (l_1*r_1*x(1))/(1+p_1*x(2))-(l_2*r_2*x(2)/(1+r_2*x(3))
endfunction

x0 = [1; 0; -1];
t = linspace(0, 2, 201);
x = lsode (@f3, x0, t);

figure(1);
plot(t, x(:,1));
xlabel('t');
ylabel('X');
title('X - component');


figure(2);
plot(t, x(:,2));
xlabel('t');
ylabel('Y');
title('Y - component');
```

should solve  the system ode but giving me

> > > f3

```
parse error near line 18 of file C:/Users/Admin/Desktop\f3.m

syntax error

>>>   xdot(2)= rM + ((r_2*p_2*x(3))/(1+p_2*x(3)))*x(2)-r_2*x(2)^2- 
(R_2*x(2))/(1+p_2*x(3))

     ^
```

Comment: how many opening and how many closing brakets do you have in the line starting with "xdot(1)="?

Comment: Good day, I appreciate it that you answer me. I correct brackets. Now appear new syntax error in endfunction........what I should do, please

Comment: add a `1;` at the very first line of your script file

Comment: Sir in the very first line I digit 1; But continue the same error...... I don't know anymore what to do..parse error near line 22 of file C:\Users\Admin\adam1.m

  syntax error

>>> endfunction
              ^

Comment: What is the dimension of the state? Why do you set the state to zero changing the dimension from 3 to 2? Did you previously use lsode successfully with some other ODE system?

Comment: Do you have reason to expect that there is a solution over the full interval [0,1]? // The expression `R-1` is probably meant to be `R_1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the derivatives function

```
function xdot = f3(x, t)
      xdot = 0*x;

      r_1=4;
      R_1=1;
      p_1=8;
      l_1=0.2;
      r_2=10;
      p_2=10;
      R_2=2;
      l_2=50;
      rM= 0.01;
      d=2;

      xdot(1)= ((r_1*p_1*x(3))/(1+p_1*x(3)))*x(1)-r_1*x(1)^2-(R_1*x(1))/(1+r_1*x(3)-x(1)*x(2));
      xdot(2)= rM + ((r_2*p_2*x(3))/(1+p_2*x(3)))*x(2)-r_2*x(2)^2-(R_2*x(2))/(1+p_2*x(3));
      xdot(3)= d - (l_1*r_1*x(1))/(1+p_1*x(2))-(l_2*r_2*x(2)/(1+r_2*x(3)));
end
```

which corrects all the errors mentioned in the comments and summarized in the answer of @lostbard, I get a solution for part of the interval. The solution blows up in the `X` component for `t` about `0.3295`, as can also be seen in the resulting plot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like several issues there.

1. You are creating xdot and x values of size 2, but accessing/setting at index 3.
2. For `xdot(1)= ((r_1*p_1*x(3))/(1+p_1*x(3)))*x(1)-r_1*x(1)^2-(R-1*x(1))/(1+r_1*x(3)-x(1)*x(2)`

   a) You are missing a ')' which is causing the syntax error.

   b) The `R-1`is is not correct - you have no 'R' so its probably meant to be R_1
3. In `xdot(3)= d - (l_1*r_1*x(1))/(1+p_1*x(2))-(l_2*r_2*x(2)/(1+r_2*x(3))`, you are missing a ')'